# Adding a customized form in front office

Tags: forms, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

What is the correct way to integrate an own HTML form on the product page of the front office? Using the displayProductAdditionalInfo hook, I can perfectly display my own *.tpl file on the product page. But: adding a form inside of the template file is not possible, because in product.tpl the form tag for the add-to-cart button is closed only AFTER the product-additional-info.tpl, and two nested forms are not allowed in HTML.
Concretely here is the relevant section of the original product.tpl file of Prestashop 1.7.7.3:

```
        <div class="product-actions">
          {block name='product_buy'}
            <form action="{$urls.pages.cart}" method="post" id="add-to-cart-or-refresh">
              <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$static_token}">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_product" value="{$product.id}" id="product_page_product_id">
              <input type="hidden" name="id_customization" value="{$product.id_customization}" id="product_customization_id">

              {block name='product_variants'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-variants.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_pack'}
                {if $packItems}
                  <section class="product-pack">
                    <p class="h4">{l s='This pack contains' d='Shop.Theme.Catalog'}</p>
                    {foreach from=$packItems item="product_pack"}
                      {block name='product_miniature'}
                        {include file='catalog/_partials/miniatures/pack-product.tpl' product=$product_pack showPackProductsPrice=$product.show_price}
                      {/block}
                    {/foreach}
                </section>
                {/if}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_discounts'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-discounts.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_add_to_cart'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-add-to-cart.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {block name='product_additional_info'}
                {include file='catalog/_partials/product-additional-info.tpl'}
              {/block}

              {* Input to refresh product HTML removed, block kept for compatibility with themes *}
              {block name='product_refresh'}{/block}
            </form>
          {/block}
```

Why do you not close the form tag of the add-to-cart-or-refresh form directly after the three input fields? Then the subsequent *.tpl files and their hooks could use forms also. Or am I missing something?

Comment: that's because, inside the hook you can get other fields maybe? Just guessing. Anyway you can give name attribute to a button like `<button type="submit" name="my_button">click me</button>`, and in you module `if(Tools::isSubmit('my_button'))`....
Or, in alternative, use a javascript function to post your data

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Jack! I am not sure, if I understand your first proposal correctly, but I guess when pressing the button, still the action URL from the original form will be called. In this case it is http://localhost/prestashop/index.php?controller=cart. This means I would have to catch my submit event in that controller. So, maybe I will better try the Javascript solution. All in all I do not want to modify the original PS files.

Comment: Correct. But what I suggest is to not edit the Prestashop core files, because all your edit will be overwrite by an update. Consider creating a module.

Comment: Hi Jack, Thanks. This is absolutely what I want to achieve. I have already started my own module and I do not want to modify any PS core files. My only question is how to submit the fields of the form to my own module. When I extend the existing add-to-cart form, I would have to modify the cart controll.  Or I try to redirect the action URL of the cart form to my own module by means of JavaScript. Something like

document.getElementById("add-to-cart-or-refresh").action     = mymodule_URL;

But this is also kind of a hack...